# Rails - uninitialized constant Admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm working to build an admin console for my app.

I added `admin_controller.rb ... class AdminController < ApplicationController`

I then added `resources :admin` to my routes.

I then added a model which is empty, as there is no DB table for the admin views, it's just reports off other tables:

```
class Admin < ActiveRecord::Base

end
```

The admin console won't have a model in the db.

When I try to access the /admin view I get the error:

```
Access denied on index Admin(Table doesn't exist)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you inherit from `ActiveRecord::Base` you're going to need a database table. If you don't need a database table then don't inherit from `ActiveRecord::Base`.

If you want to be able to use some of the features from active record, like validations or callbacks, you can include the modules you need. Here's a good write up that will explain everything:

http://yehudakatz.com/2010/01/10/activemodel-make-any-ruby-object-feel-like-activerecord/